# In-App purchase quantity limit issue

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, mkstorekit

I have a consumable product that i would like to allow user to buy many of. However, when testing the buy of more that 10 items I get the following:

[image]

Here is the code used to create the payment:

```
SKMutablePayment *payment = [SKMutablePayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:kProductID];
payment.quantity = quantity;
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
```

Is there really a limit on this, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, limit is 10

quantity
The number of items the user wants to purchase. (read-only)

@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSInteger quantity
Discussion
The default value is 1, the minimum value is 1, and the maximum value is 10.

Availability
Available in iOS 3.0 and later.
Declared In
SKPayment.h